# How to read xml in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm currently working with an SQL Server 2012 that requires me to read XML string that can be read and insert data in the table using Stored Procedure.

```
DECLARE @TurnoverList VARCHAR(Max) = "<root><data><Value>1</Value><Value>3</Value><Value>2</Value><Value>4</Value></data></root>"
DECLARE @hDocTurnover INT

EXEC Sp_Xml_prepareDocument @hDocTurnover OUTPUT
    ,@TurnoverList

SELECT *
INTO #TempTurnover
FROM OpenXml(@hDocTurnover, 'root/data', 2) WITH (Value INT)

EXEC Sp_Xml_RemoveDocument @hDocTurnover

SELECT *
FROM #TempTurnover
```

But it Currently only one record

```
Value 
------
1
```

Comment: `sp_xml_preparedocument` is a *really* old way of dealing with XML; you'll be far better off with using XUQERY. What is the expected data you're after here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply after the value of each `Value` node, you'll be better off with:

```sql
--Note use of the CORRECT datatype. Use the xml datatype for XML, for a (n)varchar
DECLARE @XML xml = '<root><data><Value>1</Value><Value>3</Value><Value>2</Value><Value>4</Value></data></root>';

SELECT d.V.value('(./text())[1]','int') AS [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/root/data/Value') d(V);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e03ea909cfbfea0ae56f1344c5ddeddf)

Comment: If it works, please consider marking it as the solution, @keavlbalar , so that future users know the answer was useful. Thanks.